# mvvm ValueCombiners() on fluent binding

Tags: ios, data-binding, mvvmcross

Is it possible to use MvxValueCombiner as described in documentation on github with fluent binding on IOs projects ?

I would like to concatenate firstname & lastname on a field like this (pseudo code)

```
set.Bind(SubRightLbl).To(vm => vm.user).Add("vm.user.firstname", "vm.user.lastname");
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this currently is to use free text in the `To` or `SourceDescribed` fluent extensions.

For example, see the ApiExamples `If` and `Maths` examples:

```
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MathsView, MathsViewModel>();
        set.Bind(label1).To(vm => vm.TestVal1);
        set.Bind(seek1).To(vm => vm.TestVal1);
        set.Bind(label2).To(vm => vm.TestVal2);
        set.Bind(seek2).To(vm => vm.TestVal2);
        labelA.Text = "Add";
        set.Bind(labelB).SourceDescribed("TestVal1 + '+' + TestVal2 + '=' + (TestVal1 + TestVal2)");
        labelC.Text = "Subtract";
        set.Bind(labelD).SourceDescribed("TestVal1 + '-' + TestVal2 + '=' + (TestVal1 - TestVal2)");
        labelE.Text = "Multiply";
        set.Bind(labelF).SourceDescribed("TestVal1 + '*' + TestVal2 + '=' + (TestVal1 * TestVal2)");
        labelG.Text = "Divide";
        set.Bind(labelH).SourceDescribed("TestVal1 + '/' + TestVal2 + '=' + (TestVal1 / TestVal2)");
        labelI.Text = "Modulo";
        set.Bind(labelJ).SourceDescribed("TestVal1 + '%' + TestVal2 + '=' + (TestVal1 % TestVal2)");
        set.Apply();
```

from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/ApiExamples/ApiExamples.Touch/Views/FirstView.cs#L699

---

Alternatively, if you wanted to create your own extension methods to provide the functionality you require, that should certainly be possible - an expression combiner like

```
    .Combine("CombinerName", "Expression0", "Expression2", ....)
```

should certainly be possible to build